# Flexbox Items per Row Responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I think that's an easy task, but I can not find the solution.

I have a Flexbox with 3 items per row. These should not complete the row completely, if there are no 3 items.

Like so:

1 2 3
4 _ _

On smaler sreens it should look like this:

1 2
3 4

But what I get is this:

1 _
2 _
3 _
4 _

```css
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex_container .third {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media(min-width:981px) {
  .flex_container .third:nth-child(3n) {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}

@media(max-width:980px) {
  .flex_container .third {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0px 5px!important;
  }
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .flex_container .third {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="third">1</div>
  <div class="third">2</div>
  <div class="third">3</div>
  <div class="third">4</div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `.flex_container .third{width:100%;}` ? you explicitly specify 100%

Answer (score 0):

you want something along the lines of (Note this has a mobile-first layout, which has several other benefits which you can Google to find out):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex_container .third {
  display: inherit;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  /* Added to show the boxes when no content */
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
  .flex_container .third{
      flex: 0 1 33%;
  }
}
```

Comment: You mixed up the percentages, but I tried your solution and the flex: 0 1 33.333% works. But if I do the same thing in @media(min-width: 768px) with flex: 0 1 50%, the boxes get 100% width.